# ggplot barplot with error bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I tried a code from one of you for drawing a barplot with error bar.

But it didn't work, I am sure that the code provide should work (the figure produced is exactly what I wanted)

Here is the code, did I miss something?

```
> my.df <- read.table(text = "group N        val         sd         se         ci
 206 3 37.2269533  7.9688645  4.6008261 19.7957568
 207 3  2.0731505  2.2843009  1.3188417  5.6745180
 208 3  2.2965978  1.4120606  0.8152536  3.5077531
 209 3  3.1085132  1.1986664  0.6920504  2.9776525
 210 3  3.3735251  1.9226134  1.1100214  4.7760365
 211 3  4.0477951  2.9410503  1.6980162  7.3059739
 212 3  1.2391158  1.2345554  0.7127709  3.0668055
 213 2  1.3082374  1.1234220  0.7943793 10.0935460", header = TRUE)
> 
> ggplot(my.df, aes(x = factor(group), y = val)) +  
   geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=val-se, ymax=val+se))
```

I had that message:

```
Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot, warn_missing = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "revalue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revalue` is a `plyr` function which has been introduced 5 months ago. Probably you are running an older version than that. Updating `plyr` and `ggplot2` should fix that problem.